# Get Model properties out of Custom T4 Controller

Tags: c#, linq, t4, scaffolding

I have a T4 (TT) controller which I want to access the model's properties from. It seems that feeding it with a model entity class resolves into

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Core.Metadata.PropertyMetadata[]
```

I'm not even sure I'm doing it right. Basically I want to list the properties as plain text (in bold below) so I can include them in a LINQ statement:

The final cs should display:

```
from person in db.Persons
select new Person
{
    **Name** = "Justin",
    **Surname** = "Farrugia",
    :
    :                                                                                                                   
}
....
```

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0):

@ASpirin, you are right I could use reflection like that but since I have a dedicated object I would prefer the below ;)

Turns out I was just missing calling them out like so:

```
<# foreach (var property in ModelMetadata.Properties) { #>
                        + <#= property.PropertyName #>
<# } #>
```

Hope this helps other new guys!